# KnpSnappyBundle not executing javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, symfony

I am using Symfony 3.1.2 with KnpSnappyBundle 1.4 and I followed everything the doc says here (to generate a pdf) : https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

But it's not working. The pdf is generated but the javascript is not executed ...

Here is my Symfony controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/report")
 */
public function report(Request $request)
{
    $idTown = 1;//$request->request->get("idTown"); 

    $html = $this->renderView("@AppBundle/Resources/views/report.html.twig", array
    (
        "idTown" => $idTown
    ));

    return new Response
    (
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html,
                array(
                    'enable-javascript' => true,
                    'no-stop-slow-scripts' => true,
                    'javascript-delay' => 5000)
        ),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
        )
    );
}
```

Here is the the HTML file (`report.html.twig`) :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $("body").html("okkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
    </script>

    <style>
        html
        {
            background-color : red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

When I go to the url `localhost/report`, I receive a download prompt for a red page with no text in it. For what it's worth, I also tried with native javascript (instead of jQuery) and it didn't work neither. But you see, the CSS is executed ...

Help please, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it. I still don't know why it wasn't working but in my experience of these html-to-pdf libraries, there is *always* something that is gonna go wrong at some point.

I managed to generate (and download) my pdf succesfully using the original tool all these libraries are built on : `wkhtmltopdf`.

Here is my code, it might help some people :

The Symfony controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/report")
 */
public function report(Request $request)
{
    $idTown = 1;//$request->request->get("idTown"); 

    exec("wkhtmltopdf --disable-smart-shrinking --no-outline --margin-top 0mm --margin-bottom 0mm --margin-right 0mm --margin-left 0mm http://localhost/test --javascript-delay 3000 rapport.pdf");

    $filename = "rapport.pdf";
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
    readfile($filename);
    unlink("rapport.pdf");

    return new Response();
}
```

The template is what you want. No problem with includes of assets, no need for absolutes paths or all that shit, etc. I basically lost 5 hours trying to different libraries to simply use `wkhtmltopdf` alone in the end ... And yes you can put the JS and CSS is separate files. I also suggest you put `wkhtmltopdf` in the PATH variable of your server, unless you want to reference the full path.

Hope it helps someone one day.

Comment: Where is the template being passed in the above function?